# what is the equivalent of YAHOO.util.Connect.asyncRequest() of YUI in jQuery?

Tags: jquery-ui

I am working on few js files and there are following functions/methods of YUI being used,I have to change\migrate them to jQuery:

```
YAHOO.util.Connect.asyncRequest();
YAHOO.util.Dom.getFirstChild(node.childNodes[i])
YAHOO.util.Dom.getAncestorByTagName(el,"ul")
YAHOO.util.Dom.getFirstChild(pqrs)
YAHOO.util.Dom.insertBefore(abcd,xyz)
```

please answer here or at my mail id,as I m stuck !

Comment: Could you paste the context of each method?

Answer (score 1):

`YAHOO.util.Connect.asyncRequest();` is the same as [jQuery's ajax method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).  You can use `$.ajax()` to do the same thing, provided you set up the same parameters.

As for your other methods?  I'd need to know where you got some of the parameters from.  But,

- `YAHOO.util.Dom.getFirstChild(node.childNodes[i])` becomes `$(node).children().eq(i).first()`
- `YAHOO.util.Dom.getAncestorByTagName(el,"ul")` becomes `$(el).parent('ul')`
- `YAHOO.util.Dom.getFirstChild(pqrs)` becomes `$(pqrs)`
- `YAHOO.util.Dom.insertBefore(abcd,xyz)` becomes `$(abcd).insertBefore(xyz)`

Comment: I was searching these methods at jQuery's site,but,I am not getting these methods there.Can you explain me why it is so?

Comment: how to get the set of nodes based on a given CSS selector in jQuery?

Comment: I can't explain why you're not finding it. Try clicking on the Documentation link and using the "Search jQuery" box at the top of the page. You can also always check Google, whose index tends to bring up better results than jQuery's search. I've verified that each function is searchable and comes up with a result. As for the set of nodes based on a given CSS selector, that's not hard. It's the argument to the jQuery $() function. I suggest working through some jQuery tutorials to get a better feel of how it all works out.